# Communication between STM32 as host and Arduino as device via USB otg_FS

Tags: arduino, usb, stm32

Is it possible to send data from USB via STM32F4 OTG FS to another MCU (Arduino, for example)? I tried STM32_USB_Host_Library and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is certainly possible.

But it may require a significant amount of work.

It will work out of the box if the Arduino supports standard USB CDC for virtual serial ports. And many do not.

For any other USB chipset you need a driver.

If you don't want to write a driver then the answer is no.